# How to increase the number of containers in nodemanager in YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

A node in my YARN cluster has 64GB memory and 24 cores. I set the following properties in the yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
  <value>32768</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
  <value>16</value>
</property>
```

But I found still the nodemanager in the node has only 7 containers. What are other properties I need to set?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to tell YARN how to break down the memory to containers so for instance if you set the memory per container to 2GB will give you 16 containers

```
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made me realize that I had a typo in my memory-mb parameter (I had used underscore instead of dash between memory and mb).

Comment: I have 7 nodes in my cluster [8GB RAM and 4VCPUs to each nodes]. There are mapreduce.jobsubmitter: number of input splits: 34 for my application.  My application is crashing at Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=134: /bin/bash: line 1:  3876 Aborted                 (core dumped) . How can avoid this? What shall be my configuration in ampred-site.xml?

Comment: @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz: A Hadoop/YARN newbie here. OP has 64GB of memory. If we allocate 2048mb (i.e. 2GB) to each container, he should get 64/2 = 32 containers. Can you explain why 16? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using map/reduce -if so you should also set the properties for map/reduce allocation (as @avner wrote below)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz - So, giving 2GB as container size would mean that my Java Xmx cannot exceed 2GB because if I do, then as Java tries to increase its heap size at runtime beyond 2GB, YARN would kill it?

Comment: As a Application Manager Framework (MapReduce or Spark for example) how do you request number of container per job. I know it can be dynmaic means AM can ask for more container during it lifecycle but what parameter it uses for that?

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>      
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>      
  </property>
```